# How to check if a button has this image

Tags: ios, swift, image, swift3, uibutton

I want to check if myButton has a named image.

I try this but it doesn't work

```
if (myButton.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "ButtonAppuyer.png")) != nil){
        print("YES")
    } else {
        print("NO")
    }
```

and this too doesn't work

```
if myButton.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "ButtonAppuyer.png")){
        print("YES")
    } else {
        print("NO")
    }
```

Comment: I thought it was not possible to check for the image stored

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what I came up with in Swift 3.0.

```
if let myButtonImage = myButton.image(for: .normal),
    let buttonAppuyerImage = UIImage(named: "ButtonAppuyer.png"),
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(myButtonImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(buttonAppuyerImage)
{
    print("YES")
} else {
    print("NO")
}
```

This could be cleaned up a lot.

```
extension UIButton {
    func hasImage(named imageName: String, for state: UIControlState) -> Bool {
        guard let buttonImage = image(for: state), let namedImage = UIImage(named: imageName) else {
            return false
        }

        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(buttonImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(namedImage)
    }
}
```

Then use it

```
if myButton.hasImage(named: "ButtonAppuyer.png", for: .normal) {
    print("YES")
} else {
    print("NO")
}
```

Comment: Instead of comparing `Data` with `Data`, I would prefer to somehow map the name of image added to button against button and then compare `String` with `String`. It would take less memory.

Comment: @AdilSoomro, you can't. The best you can do is "tag" each image and then populate the tag property of each button. But even then, how can you be *sure* the image is the same without comparing the data?

Comment: @AdilSoomro There are ways of optimizing the performance of this approach. I would only start down that route if this method was causing performance issues. I prefer to optimize for maintainability first (straight forward and readable code).

Comment: @JefferyThomas is there any way to check wether button has set any image or not?

Comment: @QadirHussain `button.image(for: .normal) != nil`

Answer (score 3):

***in swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1***

```
buttonOne.image(for: .normal)!.pngData() == UIImage(named: "selected")!.pngData()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the button's image and the named image to `NSData`s and compare the two data objects:

```
let imgData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(buttonImage)
let imgData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(namedImage)
let equal = imgData1 == imgData2
```

Note that this will only work if the two images are completely identical (e.g. come from the same source file); if one is a scaled down version of the other, it won't work.

Also, it should be mentioned that this can be a pretty expensive operation and should not be run frequently.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve the image name from a UI element. You will need to store the value you want to retrieve in another location.

For instance, you could create a custom subclass of `UIButton` that contains an additional property to store the image name or other identifying data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let ButtonImage = myButton.image(for: .normal),
    let Image = UIImage(named: "ButtonAppuyer.png"),
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(ButtonImage) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(Image)
{
    print("YES")
} else {
    print("NO")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if myCell.followButton.currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "yourImageName")) {
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: Generally, Stack Overflow prefers an explanation over "Code only" answers.  Consider adding detail on how this code answers the question.